# how to add range value to link in vba

Tags: excel, vba

i would like to add range value to my link but it is doesn't work some one can help how can i add range value to the link please?
thanks a lot

```
    Dim iLink
    Dim myUrl
    Dim Number
    
    i = 7
    Number= Range("D" & i).Value
    myUrl = "https://www.google.com/Number"

    While Range("D" & i).Value <> ""
    iLink = myUrl & Range("D" & i).Value

    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
    Anchor:=Range("D" & i).Offset(, 1), _
    Address:=iLink
    i = i + 1
    Wend
```

Comment: What does doesn't work mean? An error? Wrong output?

Comment: i mean no error but the link opened is https://www.google.com/ instead of https://www.google.com/123

Comment: Change `myUrl = "https://www.google.com/Number"` to `myUrl = "https://www.google.com/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
myUrl = "https://www.google.com/" & Number
```

Because you enclosed your variable 'Number' inside double quotes, vba counted it as a string, not a variable.

Comment: `iLink = myUrl & Range("D" & i).Value` would duplicate.

Comment: @findwindow yeah that's correct, but what if he wants it to duplicate it , our both answers are correct depending on if he wants it to duplicate it or not.

Comment: Yea, his comment says google/123 but clearly he wants google/123/123